# Training a CNN model UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am a bit confused as I never encountered such an error before. I am tryiing to train my CNN model on images. Below you can see a picture of my code, and then the error message. As you can see it starts at epoch 1 then it stops :(

Does anyone have any idea where does the problem comes from? If anyone had a similar error message before when training your CNN?

Any help is welcome,

Thanks

```
history = modelA.fit(train_data,
                        validation_data = test_data,
                        epochs = 60,
                        callbacks = [best_model, reduce_lr, es])
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Epoch 1/60
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-4b47ff852a2a> in <module>()
      2                         validation_data = test_data,
      3                         epochs = 60,
----> 4                         callbacks = [best_model, reduce_lr, es])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:
```

Comment: Please share enough code to reproduce and fix the error.

Comment: Just switch from GPU to TPU and it should be working. Please share your feedback if it is still valid to you. Similar problem has been solved in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984678/unimplementederror-graph-execution-error-running-nn-on-tensorflow). Thank you!